# Set-ExecutionPolicy gloablly for a specific script

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10, powershell-5.0

Is it possible to `Set-ExecutionPolicy` for a specific script, globally? I know it is possible to open `PowerShell` and set a policy for a specific script like so:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Script\From\Internet.ps1
```

But I am trying to set the policy for that script globally so no matter how I open `PowerShell`, it'll have that policy set for that file. That way if I open `PowerShell` from the Start menu, or if VS Code opens a `PowerShell` terminal, that script will always work/run.

The `Set-ExecutionPolicy` doesn't have a paramater for `-File` so I'm not sure how to set it globally for a specific file.

Answer (score 0):

No.

As documented, there is no concept of setting the EP at the script level.

You have to do it as you have already shown...

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Script\From\Internet.ps1
```

... which btw is not at the script level (since there is no such thing), you are the default process level.

You can add it, the EP,  to your profile(s)...

- Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
- Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1
- Microsoft.VSCode_profile.ps1

... but that applies to any PowerShell instance you start.

[Again, as documented, there are only 5 options (file/script is not one of them)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7):

1. MachinePolicy
2. UserPolicy
3. Process
4. CurrentUser
5. LocalMachine

Your only option to get close to what you are after is to create a custom shortcut on your desktop using the command you have already shown and pin that to wherever you need it.

The only real reason to change the EP is if the Machine EP is more restrictive (Restricted or AllSigned) enforce via GPO and you need to work outside that.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't see any documentation saying that there is no concept of setting the EP at the script level and I didn't want to make any assumptions. I will look into setting it at those profiles.

Comment: You can also just create a custom Powershell short cut on your desktop/taskbar and set it to run launch with whatever EP you choose. Just pin it to your taskbar for quick access. I do this regularly, our machine level EP are set at AllSigned or Restricted (depending on where I am), and I need to dev/test in a more relaexed use case daily. The EP does not affect code executed in the ISE/VSCode editor pane via F5/F8.

Comment: The thing is, I could start PS numerous ways, from a shortcut to Start > type PowerShell > enter. I don't know enough about the PowerShell profile scripts -- that might work for me once I figure it out.

Comment: What would you do if you want the file `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` to be the one that bypasses the policy? Since you cannot add the command to your profile, because is the file you want to be affected by it.